Rarity of $1$ in the sequence of the first digits of the powers of $2$
The sequence of the first digits of the powers of $2$ is $1, 2, 4, 8, 1, 3, 6, 1, ...$.
Arnold says that one can use dynamical system theory to prove that the rarity of 1-s in this sequence is approximately 30%.
Is there an elementary proof (without using dynamical systems theory)?

this is fairly elementary.

Oh, my question is a duplicate. I will close it.
